# Nokogiri Builder will omit xmlns attribute if already used

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, nokogiri

I'm trying to build an xml spreadsheet that contains styles that will be opened in excel.

This is my code:

```
res = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Workbook 'xmlns' => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet", 
                'xmlns:o'    => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office",
                'xmlns:x'    => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel",    
                'xmlns:html' => "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40",
                'xmlns:ss'   => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" do

    xml.WorksheetOptions "xmlns" => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" do
      xml.PageSetup do
        xml.Layout "x:Orientation" => "Landscape"
        xml.Header "x:Data" => "&LLeft side&CCenter&R&D &T"
        xml.Footer "x:Data" => "&CPage: &P / &N"
      end

      xml.Unsynced
      xml.FitToPage

      xml.Print do
        xml.FitHeight 20
        xml.ValidPrinterInfo
        xml.Scale 90
        xml.HorizontalResolution -4
        xml.VerticalResolution -4
      end

      xml.Zoom 125
      xml.PageLayoutZoom 0
      xml.Selected
      xml.Panes do
        xml.Pane do
          xml.Number 3
          xml.ActiveRow 8
          xml.ActiveCol 4
        end
      end
      xml.ProtectObjects "False"
      xml.ProtectScenarios "False"

      xml.AllowFormatCells
      xml.AllowSizeCols
      xml.AllowSizeRows
      xml.AllowSort
      xml.AllowFilter
      xml.AllowUsePivotTables
    end
  end
end.to_xml
puts res
```

I had this as a working template for years (I was using bunlder's builder before which now is just too slow) and now that I switched to Nokogiri it's not working anymore. Basically this: `"xmlns" => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"` in the `WorksheetOptions` tag get's ignored and is not added to the document. Here is the actual result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <WorksheetOptions>
    <PageSetup>
      <Layout x:Orientation="Landscape"/>
      <Header x:Data="&amp;LLeft side&amp;CCenter&amp;R&amp;D &amp;T"/>
      <Footer x:Data="&amp;CPage: &amp;P / &amp;N"/>
    </PageSetup>
    <Unsynced/>
    <FitToPage/>
    <Print>
      <FitHeight>20</FitHeight>
      <ValidPrinterInfo/>
      <Scale>90</Scale>
      <HorizontalResolution>-4</HorizontalResolution>
      <VerticalResolution>-4</VerticalResolution>
    </Print>
    <Zoom>125</Zoom>
    <PageLayoutZoom>0</PageLayoutZoom>
    <Selected/>
    <Panes>
      <Pane>
        <Number>3</Number>
        <ActiveRow>8</ActiveRow>
        <ActiveCol>4</ActiveCol>
      </Pane>
    </Panes>
    <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
    <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
    <AllowFormatCells/>
    <AllowSizeCols/>
    <AllowSizeRows/>
    <AllowSort/>
    <AllowFilter/>
    <AllowUsePivotTables/>
  </WorksheetOptions>
</Workbook>
```

If I write anything else as the `xmlns` attribute on this line `xml.WorksheetOptions "xmlns" => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" do` it will work and get added correctly to the document.

This is wrong, apparently excel will not set the page properly if that attribute is missing. Is this a correct behavior for Nokogiri?

If it is, is there any other way to make excel apply the correct page layout to the document?

This happens with another tag that I didn't include in the example, otherwise it would have been too long. This is the other one: `xml.DocumentProperties("xmlns" => "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office") do`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the builder interface, but you can always add it directly to a node by using `add_namespace` with a `nil` namespace:

```
node.add_namespace(nil, "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel")
```

See the documentation on [Node#add_namespace](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-add_namespace) for details.